# Xcode Simulator with Master-Detail View

Tags: ios, ipad, swift

I created a new Project as Master-Detail view application. When I run the project with IPad simulator I can only see Master View where as I was expecting to see both Master as well as Detail view together. Please let me know if there is a setting with I am missing. I was expecting this behavior for Iphone as due to small screen size.

Thanks,

Dev

Comment: How did you create your project? Is it universal?

Comment: are you sure? are you not in fact seeing only the *detail* view?

Comment: I created for iPhone mode only. I re-created the project with different name and when executed it aborts with following message: "reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run the project with IPad simulator I can only see Master View where as I was expecting to see both Master as well as Detail view together

One possibility: When you created the project, you neglected the pop-up menu where you set your project as iPhone, iPad, or Universal. Therefore you accidentally created an iPhone app — an iPhone *only* app.

Thus, even on an iPad, you are running inside the iPhone emulator and seeing, enlarged, what you would see on an iPhone.

Solution: start over, and this time, pay attention to that pop-up menu.

---

Another possibility: You are holding the iPad in portrait orientation. Seeing only the Detail view is correct behavior in this orientation. The default project template provides a button at top left that summons the Master view in a sort of popover, or you can swipe from the left, or you can rotate the iPad to landscape, in order to see the Master view side by side with the Detail view.

Comment: Hi Matt - You are right, I neglected Universal part of it. I re-created it as Universal application with core data enabled. I was able to successfully run the application without modifying anything. But then I added an Entity called BlogItems with four attributes which are all string. I try to re-run the project and it aborts with following error:" reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store". I reverted back the changes with Command+Z and it works fine again. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong this time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Asking a new question as a comment is called "leeching". Do not leech, please. If you have a new question, ask a new question! Meanwhile, I believe I have answered correctly the question you did ask, so it would be polite to accept it (checkmark) if so. Thank you.

Comment: Matt - Thanks for letting me know. As you can tell I am new to both Stack Overflow and Swift. I will ask my question as a new post. Thanks for your help.